# ThreadPoolExecutor does not shrink properly

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I was handled a design of a threaded application that has the following requirement: It has to have a dynamic number of threads it runs based on the time of day (Peak/off-peak).

I did my homework and researched for the best way to do this, and I found that java has a class named ThreadPoolExecutor:
`java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue)`

The two variables in focus here are the corePoolSize, and the maximumPoolSize, both act as the lower and the upper bound of the thread pool along with the workQueue. tuning these values have different strategies and it is advisable to use the executer factory methods instead of the constructor in case these parameters are not needed to be set explicitly.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100);
        final ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
        threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                try {
                    executor.getQueue().put(r);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadPool.setCorePoolSize(1);
                threadPool.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
                System.out.println("changed");
            }
        };
        new Timer().schedule(task, 10000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            threadPool.submit(new WorkItem(i));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class that resembles the thread to run

```
public class WorkItem implements Runnable {
    private int workItemNumber;
    private long startTime;

    public WorkItem(int workItemNumber) {
        this.workItemNumber = workItemNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("thread Number: " + workItemNumber + " started at: " + startTime);
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 5000) {
        }
        System.out.println("WorkItem done: " + workItemNumber);
    }
}
```

However, looking at the logs, the number of executed threads remain the same with no change.

Comment: Please don't name your class `Thread`.

Comment: Why would you expect a different number of executed threads when you have a for loop which generates 400 threads to run?  The only thing you're changing is how many execute in parallel (10 down to 1 after 10 seconds, and then repeatedly setting it to 1 every 5 seconds)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis changed it to WorkItem, I am not sure how that can help though

Comment: @Foosh This is exactly my problem, the logs show more than the number of threads configured starting simultaneously.

Comment: @Mahm0ud It's misleading and conflicts with `java.lang.Thread` which the compiler automatically imports for you in all your source files.

Comment: What does your output say up until, including, and shortly after the "changed" line?

Comment: @Foosh I did add the additional logs you suggested in the code along with the start time adjustment, the logs are :
http://pastebin.com/XvCxdywF

Comment: Hmm I used your code exactly and here's my [result](http://pastebin.com/CeuD21gw)  I'm using java 8u11 and 7u65 and see similar results in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is running exactly as you intend it to.  10 threads are started and run, and 100 threads are queued.  At that point, your main thread (the one queuing threads) is blocked by the blocking queue.  Your timer then changes the available threads to 1, meaning your queue processes even slower.  What you are seeing however, is that because your threads have to wait for longer than 10 seconds to actually execute they complete immediately.  Try making the following changes to your code:

```
public class WorkItem implements Runnable {
    private long startTime;
    private long runTime;
    private int workItemNumber;

    public WorkItem(long startTime, int workItemNumber) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.workItemNumber= workItemNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("WorkItem started: " + workItemNumber + " Queued at: " + startTime);
        runTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() - runTime < 10000) {
        }
        System.out.println("WorkItem done: " + workItemNumber);
    }
}
```

This will let you see the execution occurring as you would expect.  The strange thing about using an array blocking queue with your core pool set to 0 is that it'll only start a single thread, then fill up the queue, then start more threads (up to max pool size).  You can see this happening if you make a subtle change to your queuing code.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new WorkItem(System.currentTimeMillis(), i));
}

for (int i = 101; i < 401; i++) {
    long thisTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    threadPool.submit(new WorkItem(System.currentTimeMillis(), i));
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - thisTime < 500) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, however as I answered @Sotirios, even if you decrease the timer delay to 100 or 200 mills, you'd still get the same behavior of as many threads fired together

Comment: No, you really don't.  I tested your code out in eclipse and watched the active threads in the debugger.  Your output likely says this:  0, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108 as the first 10 threads that start.  Then later on it looks like you have 200 threads run at once but that's because of the faulty logic in your thread timer, not your main program.

Comment: Thanks again for drawing my attention to my programmatic error in thread time out, however the issue still persists, I did open the debugger and I do not see any changes in the number of threads.
That being said I could only see a change in debugger after the first loop ended and the code entered the second loop.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a pool with 10 max threads

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

and you've submitted 400 tasks

```
for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
    threadPool.submit(new Thread(System.currentTimeMillis(), i));
}
```

The thread pool will not use more than 10 threads (threads represented by the `java.lang.Thread` class) to execute your tasks.

Submitting and executing all these tasks takes less than the 10000 millisecond delay you've set for your `TimerTask`

```
new Timer().schedule(task, 10000, 5000);
```

Once your `TimerTask` is run, your pool will only have one thread running and claiming submitted tasks (once the other threads' tasks are completed).

---

Sample that will show that only one thread will remain in the `ThreadPoolExecutor` once the `TimerTask` has been executed (and after any executing tasks finish)

```
public class Jackson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100);
        final ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
        threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
            public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
                try {
                    executor.getQueue().put(r);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                threadPool.setCorePoolSize(1);
                threadPool.setMaximumPoolSize(1);
                System.out.println("changed");
                this.cancel();
            }
        };
        new Timer().schedule(task, 5, 5000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            threadPool.submit(new WorkItem(i));
        }
    }
}

class WorkItem implements Runnable {
    private int workItemNumber;

    public WorkItem(int workItemNumber) {
        this.workItemNumber = workItemNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("WorkItem #" + workItemNumber + " executing on Thread with name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try to zero the delay on the timer and I still do get the same results

Comment: @Mahm0ud Remember these things are all asynchronous. You can't guarantee order of execution from the thread scheduling system. You can influence it. If you add a `Thread.sleep` between submitting the `TimerTask` and your for loop, you should only see one thread used by the thread pool.

Comment: I did have the same idea: if I add a _this.wait()_ to the thread _run()_ method, then the thread becomes idle which gives the pool the chance to destroy it, however on the eclipse debugger I still can see the thread as long as I am in the loop

Comment: @Mahm0ud No, that's not what idle means. Idle means that there is no work for the pool to do. That's when threads are removed from the pool. When you do `this.wait` within a task, the current thread is doing work, it's executing the task's code.

Comment: I am talking about the WorkItem thread, and as for idle threads, and correct me if I am wrong, there are mainly three related states in which a thread is considered idle:
BLOCKED
WAITING
TIMED_WAITING

Comment: @Mahm0ud A `WorkItem` is not a thread. It is a `Runnable`. The `Executor` maintains a pool of threads. You submit a `WorkItem` to the `Executor`. It adds it to a queue. The threads the pool maintains all wait for something to be added to the queue and remove tasks as they become available, and then execute them. You can call those states _idle_ if you want, but that's not how the `ThreadPoolExecutor` uses it.

Comment: @Mahm0ud _idle_ to the `ThreadPoolExecutor` means that there is no work for the threads to do.

Comment: @Mahm0ud Note that a `Thread` instance is not a thread either. It only represents one. Invoking `start` actually creates and starts the thread.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did add a sleep between each thread submit within the loop, however still getting the same number of threads.
Based on your explanation, I would need to make the thread Idle first before the pool executer eliminates it from the thread pool. The question is how can that be achieved

Comment: @Mahm0ud I've updated with code to demonstrate how only one thread remains after the `TimerTask` runs. You should see all tasks run on the same thread after the `"changed"` gets printed (and any tasks that were running come to an end).

Comment: For the thread counting I am using the normal eclipse debugger.
Removing the While loop from the task sort of worked, The thing I saw after experimenting with different setups is that if the workItem added takes time in execution, the thread associated with that item remains.

Comment: @Mahm0ud Yes, as long as `WorkItem#run` hasn't finished executing, the pool is not going to reclaim the thread executing it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71180/discussion-between-mahm0ud-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: In the code you edited, it does only work because you removed the time consuming mockup (the while loop), however if you add any other time consuming process (copying for instance) it wouldn't work as expected

Comment: @Mahm0ud Your expectations are wrong. Once the max has be reset, that's how many threads will remain in the pool. Adding the long working task simply keeps the threads around longer.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst using this on later version of JDK/Grails setting max poolSize reducing it all works well in older versions of grails and JDK7. (Unsure where the problem resides I had to do this)

```
private static final int actualPoolSize =  Holders.grailsApplication.config.maximumPoolSize ?: 3
    private static int maxPoolSize = actualPoolSize
public EnhancedExecutor() {
        super(maxPoolSize,maxPoolSize,keepAliveTime,timeoutUnit,new PriorityBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxQueue))
    }
public void setMaxPoolSize(int i) {
        this.maxPoolSize=i
        super.purge()
        super.setCorePoolSize(i?:actualPoolSize)        
        super.setMaximumPoolSize(i?:actualPoolSize)
    }
```

Without the purge I could increase to a higher level without any errors. Attempting to reduce returned a null for i . or actualPoolSize. (did not seem to want to shrink without throwing an exception).

I took on comments from BretC about threads being busy and it appears purge solves that by ensuring all is reset before attempting to reset superValues

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "Set maximum pool size" method will reduce the number of idle threads only...

```
public void setMaximumPoolSize(int maximumPoolSize) {
    if (maximumPoolSize <= 0 || maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    this.maximumPoolSize = maximumPoolSize;
    if (workerCountOf(ctl.get()) > maximumPoolSize)
        interruptIdleWorkers();
}
```

If threads stay busy, it doesn't look like they are released.

(I could be wrong... It doesn't look like anything magical happens when a thread is finished to clean things up - need to take more of a look...)

Comment: That is a good point, the document stats that _italic_"Sets the maximum allowed number of threads. This overrides any value set in the constructor. If the new value is smaller than the current value, excess existing threads will be terminated when they next become idle", but even when I add wait() to the threads the behavior remains the same

Comment: Before acquiring the next task in the thread pool task queue, the executor culls any extra threads (if there are more than max).