# ThreadPoolExecutor limited number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create a ThreadPoolExecutor with a certain number of threads, but at the same time, i want to control the size of the pool queue. So I created the executor using the full constructor:

```
 BlockingQueue<Runnable> pq =
     new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(MAX_THREADPOOL_SIZE);
 ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor =
     new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadSize, threadSize, THREAD_IDLE_WAIT,
          TimeUnit.SECONDS, pq);
```

However, this gives me an `IllegalArgumentException`. If I change the constructor to

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadSize, **threadSize+1**, THREAD_IDLE_WAIT,
     TimeUnit.SECONDS, pq);
```

it works. Why won't it work if I want the ideal and max amount of threads to be the same.

Comment: What's the message of the IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: It just says the cause is a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Include full stack trace, plz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue%29):  if corePoolSize, or keepAliveTime less than zero, or if maximumPoolSize less than or equal to zero, or if **corePoolSize greater than maximumPoolSize**. So they can also be equal. I have also tried constructing with equal values and it works. Maybe the source code can help you find out what the problem is:

```
if (corePoolSize < 0 ||
    maximumPoolSize <= 0 ||
    maximumPoolSize < corePoolSize ||
    keepAliveTime < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Comment: Wow, it was a logic error in my program. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why your initial code should have thrown.  If you provide the *full* exception in the future, we can provide more specific help.

One thing to remember is that using a bounded `BlockingQueue` will throw an exception once the queue is full.  This is rarely what you'd expect.  If you take a look at my answer to the following question, you will see that you need to configure a `RejectedExecutionHandler`:

> [How can I make ThreadPoolExecutor command wait if there's too much data it needs to work on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353173/how-can-i-make-threadpoolexecutor-command-wait-if-theres-too-much-data-it-needs/10353250#10353250)

To copy from there, you need to do something like the following:

```
final BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(200);
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
           0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
// by default (unfortunately) the ThreadPoolExecutor will throw an exception
// when you submit the 201st job, to have it block you do:
threadPool.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
   public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
      // this will block if the queue is full
      executor.getQueue().put(r);
   }
});
```

Lastly, if your max-thread size is greater than the core-thread size, you must realize that the queue will fill *before* any additional threads over the core-size are allocated.  Strange but true.

Answer (score -1):

Use the factory method for a constant number of threads instead.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Then set your timeout however you need.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor exec = (ThreadPoolExecutor)Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadSize);
exec.setKeepAliveTime(THREAD_IDLE_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I tried that at first, but I want to limit the number of jobs that would build up on a queue. By default, it would be unbounded, that's why I used the normal constructor so I could pass my own data structure.